# Log transforming axis when coord_flip() is used

Tags: r, ggplot2

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxAbB.jpg) I am trying to log transform the axis on the bottom of the graph, but I think `coord_flip()` is somehow inhibiting this. I've tried using `scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")`, `coord_trans(y = "log10")` and `scale_y_log10()`. None of these worked to log transform that axis. This is the code with no transformation and the output.

[data set in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxAbB.jpg)
[dput(df)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbzO4.jpg)
Plot with no transformation

[image: Plot with no transformation]

Any help is much appreciated!

```
p1 <-ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = Quintile, y = OR, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper))+
  geom_pointrange(aes(col = Quintile))+
  geom_hline(aes(fill = Quintile), yintercept = 1, linetype = 2)+
  labs(x = "Treatment",  y = "OR and 95% CI")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper, col = Quintile), width = 0.5)+
  facet_wrap(~TX, strip.position = "left", nrow = 5,scales = "free_y")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0,vjust = 1,angle = 180, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "NULL")+
  coord_flip()
p1
```

Comment: Hi Heather, could you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question? By doing so, other can reproduce the error and try to address it. Using `scale_y_log10()` followed by `coord_flip()` should keep the log scale.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Most ggplot geoms work fine since v3.3.0 in 2020 with the x/y specified in the order you want them, so most (all?) uses of coord_flip can be avoided.  https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#bi-directional-geoms-and-stats

Comment: @RuiBarradas I added in the data set. I don't know how to make the plot without coord_flip. Everything I've tried without it looks really strange. Thank you all for your help.